# Compatibility between XAMPP and TestLink versions for installation

Tags: xampp, testlink

I'm looking to install TestLink in my local development environment using XAMPP. However, I'm seeking information about the specific versions of XAMPP and TestLink that are compatible with each other. My goal is to ensure a successful installation without compatibility issues.

Can anyone provide information about tested and documented version combinations that are known to be compatible? Additionally, is there a reliable resource or source where I can find this information?

I appreciate in advance any guidance or shared experience regarding installing TestLink in an updated XAMPP environment.

Answer (score 1):

What I can assure you is that version 1.9.19 and 1.9.20 of Testlink is compatible with version 7.3.27 of xampp (linux, in my case ubuntu 22.04)